# String parsing vs Database querying

Tags: python, mysql, string-parsing

I have a MySQL table with this data:

```
TempID    TempName       TempString 
1         aaa            34:56:23:45:67:55
2         bbb            12:56:67:45:33:99
```

I want to perform a calculation which requires splitting `TempString` into its individual values, such as 34, 56, 23..., for example.

Which is the best way:

1. Do string parsing in python and using its value
2. Separate table for storing values with `TempID`

   ```
   ValID     TempID     Value
   1         1          34
   2         1          56
   3         1          23
   4         1          45
   5         1          67
   6         1          55
   7         2          12
   8         2          56
   9         2          67
   ```

   Query to get the value for each TempID and do calculation

Kindly suggest the best way to do this.

Comment: These are two *very* different approaches. Third option would be to split the values in `TempString` to separate columns in the same table.

Comment: it is best to do python string parsing

Comment: @ vhu, value count may be differ so it cant predict. so making columns in same table is not good

Comment: Best solution would be to normalise you database design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the big question is, is it semantically correct to break those values?

When designing databases tables, it is necessary to think about domain definition of every column. Every data item stored inside of one column should be atomic (non-decomposable). This means that item stored in a column is an element of the domain defined for a particular column. This can be referred to as a domain integrity constraint (check wikipedia article on [data integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) for more info).

You can use a simple heuristic as a help in making a final decision: do you ever need, or will you ever need, to use part of the stored string for searching, i.e. inside of `where` clause. If yes, break the string into separate table columns, otherwise just parse it using Python.

A simple example of breaking the domain integrity is having a table for storing blog posts, where all tags for a single post are joined into a big string and stored into only one row, instead of having a separate table which connects posts to tags.

An obvious example of when it's okay to store relatively complex value into one column is storing dates. Even though it is composed of multiple values, full date is not complete (atomic) without all the information about year, month, day...

Answer (score 0):

Let's evaluate your two options first.

**Option 1:**

You should retrieve the temp id as string and split it with colon as your delimiter.The syntax of the split function is

```
str.split(str="", num=string.count(str)).
```

The default delimiter is space.The problem with this approach is you should create a mapping in your python script which point each tempid to all possible values retrieved.The advantage of this approach is you can avoid redundant data like temp id in the database.Although it is possible to employ normalization forms and better organize the data.

**Option 2:**

It's a simple way to implement your requirements even though not the optimal way.

**Option 3:**

Use regular expressions.Check this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

txt='30:24:33:55:60'

re1='(\\d)' 
re2='(\\d)' 
re3='.*?'   
re4='(\\d)' 
re5='(\\d)'
re6='.*?'   
re7='(\\d)' 
re8='(\\d)'
re9='.*?'   
re10='(\\d)'    
re11='(\\d)'    
re12='.*?'  
re13='(\\d)'    
re14='(\\d)'    

rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13+re14,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    d1=m.group(1)
    d2=m.group(2)
    d3=m.group(3)
    d4=m.group(4)
    d5=m.group(5)
    d6=m.group(6)
    d7=m.group(7)
    d8=m.group(8)
    d9=m.group(9)
    d10=m.group(10)
    print "("+d1+")"+"("+d2+")"+"("+d3+")"+"("+d4+")"+"("+d5+")"+"("+d6+")"+"("+d7+")"+"("+d8+")"+"("+d9+")"+"("+d10+")"+"\n"

Output: (3) (0) (2) (4) (3) (3) (5) (5) (6) (0)
```

You can strip the braces and split the string into two-two digits and use it in your queries.Advantage is you need not change the table structure.Constraint is difficult to write regular expression.This is the optimal way of achieving your goal.

**Option 4:**

Use REGEXP in mysql query.The problem is mysql regular expressions use POSIX standards and to convert the regular expression which I gave above to this standard you should do some replacements like //d to digit or [0-9] and *? to ^ and some more which I am not aware of shame on me but this type of execution will improve your query performance especially when you use indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution is best. Normalise you database, with an extra table to store those values.

Multiple columns makes it difficult when the number of values changes (and also stops you easily using aggregate functions if required).

Retrieving all the values to a script them splitting them up is possible, but again stops you using the power of the database (and possibly forces you to return far more rows than required, as you are returning them before performing a calculation which might well define whether you needed to return them).

Delimited lists in databases are a pain. However you can probably split it up to insert into your new table with a query such as this:-

```
SELECT NULL, sometable.TempID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sometable.TempString, ':', aCnt), ':'. -1)
FROM sometable
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 1+ units.i + tens.i * 10 AS aCnt
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
) sub0
WHERE aCnt <= (LENGTH(sometable.TempString) - LENGTH(REPLACE(sometable.TempString,':', '' )))
```

This will cope with up to 100 values but easy to expand.